Error while building apk in workflow due to connectivity_plus
I am trying to run my workflow but it stops at the line where apk is being released. It does not make a problem when I build the apk locally in my console.
The issue is maybe caused due the package connectivity_plus. I am using its latest version i.e. 6.0.3.
WORKFLOW:
main.yaml
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: 'stable'
          flutter-version: '3.19.6'

      - run: flutter clean
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter pub run build_runner build

      - name: Build APK
        run: flutter build apk --release

      - name: Upload APK to Firebase App Distribution
        uses: wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action@v1
        with:
          appId: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
          serviceCredentialsFileContent: ${{ secrets.CREDENTIAL_FILE_CONTENT }}
          groups: testers
          file: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk

THE ERROR:
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 35.0.1)".
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 35.0.1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform-Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platform-tools
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 35.0.1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 35.0.1)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android Emulator accepted.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 34.2.15)".
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 34.2.15)" ready.
Installing Android Emulator in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/emulator
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 34.2.15)" complete.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 34.2.15)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/tools
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':package_info_plus:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> error: invalid source release: 17

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 49s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          230.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

WHAT I TRIED
Downgrading connectivity_plus
Setting sdk to sdk: ">=3.2.0 <4.0.0"
How can I resolve it? I tried to search but nothing worked for me.

I had this problem today. You now have to set up your own java in order for this to work. Add this step between checkout and subosito/flutter-action@v2:
- name: Set up JDK 17
  uses: actions/setup-java@v3
  with:
    distribution: 'temurin'
    java-version: '17'

